# How is spectral energy density measured?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

It has been my misconception that Plank's law for black body radiation is a function that relates 
intensity of cavity radiation 
to energy of radiation & temperature of the walls of the cavity.

However, I have recently found out that Plank's law gives us the relation between energy $\textbf{density}$ and energy of radiation & temperature of the walls of the cavity.

I understand how a detector is able to measure power per surface area, photoelectric detectors are an example. However, I do not know how did physicists measure the energy density emitted from a cavity, to be able to experimentally confirm it with Plank's law.

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward relationship between spectral flux and spectral energy density.

If the hole at the edge of a cavity has an area $A$, then it emits a flux of $\pi A B_{\nu}$ W/Hz, where $B_{\nu}$ would be the Planck function written as a specific intensity (the usual form).

The factor of $\pi$ is the integral of $\cos \theta$ over the half sphere above the surface. The derivation can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).

If you wish to work in terms of specific energy density $u_{\nu}$, instead of specific intensity, then for isotropic blackbody radiation $B_{\nu} = (c/4\pi) u_{\nu}$